# Obj-c method with nullable return value not properly converting to swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a problem where the following OBJ-C method will not translate to Swift with optional return value:

```
- (nullable id)executeRequest:(ServerRequest *)request returningResponse:(__nullable NSURLResponse **__nullable)responseRef errorRef:(NSError **)errorRef
```

When trying to override that method in a swift class it translates to this:

```
override func executeRequest(request: ServerRequest, returningResponse responseRef: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?>) throws -> AnyObject
```

Note that the return value is **AnyObject** instead of **AnyObject?**

What am I doing wrong here?
I'm using X-Code 7 Beta 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift imports Objective-C methods that produce an error (`out NSError **` as its last parameter) as a throwing method (`throws`). Because the method throws, the return type is non-optional. The contract is that if a `nil` result is produced, then the method must throw an error.

Comment: Damn, ok... My Obj-c method CAN actually return nil, and not really have produced an error. Guess I'll solve it in some other way. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: When returning nil, assign an error to the error pointer, even if it's not a serious error, just to add some context as to why the object is nil.

Comment: Thanks! I'll revisit my API design :)